# Windows 7 Internet Connection Dropping Randomly

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection

Recently installed Windows 7, and everything is fine, except that my internet connection is now dropping randomly.

I've checked around and see that this is a pretty common issue, but haven't found a solution that works for me yet.

**Description of Problem:**

Every few minutes, my internet access will go away.

The problem is for this computer only - everything else on my network is fine.

This computer, and all devices on my network have static internal ips (192.168.0.X).

When it goes down, if I wait a minute or two and try again, it will be back up.

When it's down, I still have access within my network, just no internet access.

When it's down, if I ping a domain, I get a reply from my router 192.168.0.1 saying "destination net unreachable.

I have this computer, and all on my network using a local server for DNS (for local staging domains).  This has never been a problem before, and doesn't seem to be for any other devices, still.

If I try ipconfig /release, it says no adapter is in a state permissable for this opperation.

Ipconfig /all shows two new sections, tunnel adapter isatap, and tunnel adapter teredo tunneling psudo interface.  Never had these before, but assume they are something to do with Windows 7/ip6.  Both say media disconnected.

**Things I have tried that didn't fix the problem:**

Verified and updated my network card drivers.

Disabled ipv6.

Verified my IP address, that there are no conflicts on the network, and that the router is properly configured.

Disabled Windows firewall and all security / virus software.

Checked that the DNS server, gateway, etc. are properly configured on this box.

So, I'm a bit stumped.  Before I start to really dissect this thing, anyone have any ideas what's going on?  My gut says it's something to do with ipv6, or something new with Windows 7 that I'm not familiar with, but hey, who knows...?

**EDIT**

It's wired.  Some other devices on the network are wireless, but this one is wired.

Comment: Wireless or Ethernet?

Comment: Update your ethernet driver.

Comment: Is your local DNS server the ONLY DNS in the problematic computer's IP settings?  Is that DNS server properly setup to forward unanswered requests to an upstream DNS server (like your ISP, or OpenDNS, etc.)?  Since you say it's wired, have you tried a new network cable?

Comment: @techie007 - Yes, it's the only DNS server for this box.  It does forward to an external server at the ISP.  It's the same setup I had in XP, and was working.  I haven't tried a new cable yet, since this started at exactly the same time I installed windows 7.  I will try a new cable right now though.

Comment: Try changing the lan wire

read this

http://superuser.com/questions/96998/windows-7-intermittently-drops-wired-internet-lan-connection